# Haskell syntax regarding pattern matching in functions

Tags: function, haskell, pattern-matching, tuples

Ok so I'm looking at this function:

```
myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength [] = 0
myLength (x:xs) = 1 + myLength xs
```

But what I'm confused about is the last line. This part in particular: `(x:xs)`

When implementing this I used square brackets instead because i figured it's a list and I'm separating its first element from the rest of its elements. How is it a tuple?

Also it seems like a bit of a mismatch between the second line and third line. Why can that be an empty array but the next line is a tuple? This is what I originally had and thought it made the most sense but it throws an error.

```
myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength [] = 0
myLength [x:xs] = 1 + myLength xs
```

How can I know when to use parenthesis and when to use square brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(x:xs)` is not a tuple. The parentheses are just there to express precedence.
`x:xs` is a pattern that matches the list constructor (which is the infix operator `:`, often pronounced 'cons') where the list head is bound to the variable `x` and the tail is bound to the variable `xs`.
Because of Haskell's precedence rules, your third line without parentheses

```
myLength x:xs = 1 + myLength xs
```

would be parsed as

```
(myLength x):xs = 1 + myLength xs
```

which doesn't make any sense, so you need to enclose the list pattern in parentheses.

Your second version of the third line is syntactically valid, but doesn't mean what you think it means (and doesn't have the right type here). In general, `[foo]` is a list literal, in this case representing a single-element list containing `foo`. You could also write `[foo]` as `foo:[]`, they're different notations for the same thing.
Your second version `[x:xs]` mixes both these notations and would actually represent a nested list, equivalent to `(x:xs):[]`, i.e. a single-element list containing a non-empty list.